# What is the name of these display machines used inside libraries?

Tags: word-choice

They are obsolete now, but I see them often in movies. They are some sort of slide-show projector with a rotating handle that flips to new slide? I uploaded pic of the machine and the displayed slide.

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Comment: Is there a hypernym for the class that includes 'microfiche reader' & 'microfilm reader?'

Comment: +Kris, Microform - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microform.

Comment: Holy cowabunga!!! You must be so young to this world that you don't know that microfiche and microfilm had been common terms prior to 25 years ago.

You are probably also asking why

- you **dial** a number on a cell phone;
- you watch a **film** on a DVD movie.

Answer (score 6):

I have no idea what this has to do with English, but those are called [microfiche readers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microfilm_reader) in our language.

Comment: I can't see the front of the machine so I can't tell if these would be for microfiche or microfilm.

Comment: It appears to me that the machine partially visible qt the right may be a microfilm reader, and that the other three may be the microfiche reader as tchrist ventured. The difference is that microfilm readers are designed to handle roll stock, and microfiche readers take sheet stock. In terms of the media itself, the images on microfilm are the size of a 35 mm negative image (that is, about 25 mm high x 37 mm wide), while images on microfiche may be much smaller.  The machines aren't obsolete, being still used in libraries, as not all microfiche or microfilm has been converted to digital.

Comment: "[Microfilm Reader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microfilm_reader) is a device used for reading of documents stored as microform. Microform includes Flat Film, Microfilm, Aperture Cards, Microfiche, and ultra fiche. Using open reels or cassettes, Microfilm is often used as a way to store many documents in a small space. It has become increasingly important in the development of films as well as storage of archived newspapers... A microfilm reader is used in projecting and viewing to magnify microfilm images to readable proportions."

Comment: What 'language' is  'microfiche readers,' then? :)

Comment: I would venture that those are microfilm readers, partly on account of the rotating knob on the side which is used to advance the film, and partly because there is no evidence of the characteristic sliding tray at the bottom where the operator can move the medium manually. Also, they are somewhat larger than any microfiche reader I have ever used, but that's less compelling on its own as a basis for accepting my opinion.

Comment: @Kris If someone doesn’t know something is in their own language, it makes no sense to ask about it in English. They should figure it out in their own language and then look up the translation.  Identifying random objects that the querent simply has never happened to have seen before is outside the remit of English Language and Usage.

Comment: Ok, great! What are those called in *any* other language?